# How to handle the following dynamic ID through Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Would you mind helping me to understand how I can handle this dynamic ID?
Here are cases which I have already tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'Username')]")).sendKeys("aaa");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id,'undefined-undefined-Username-')]")).sendKeys("aaa");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='text']")).sendKeys("aaa");
```

No way to find that element.

[image]

Comment: plz paste bit more html code to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the element is a *dynamic* element . To invoke `click()` on the desired element you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for^='undefined-undefined-Username-']")).sendKeys("aaa");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(@for,'undefined-undefined-Username-')][contains(.,'Username')]")).sendKeys("aaa");
  ```

---

### Update

As the element is dynamic you may need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("label[for^='undefined-undefined-Username-']"))).sendKeys("aaa");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(@for,'undefined-undefined-Username-')][contains(.,'Username')]"))).sendKeys("aaa");
  ```